# mac os: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: lxml

Tags: python, macos

when i input `scrapy` using terminal, the output is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: lxml
```

then i searched some solutions around this problem in stackoverflow, then maybe i should run `sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml` and `sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml`, the result are below

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.5.0
Processing lxml-3.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
lxml 3.5.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml
Finished processing dependencies for lxml

sudo easy_install --upgrade scrapy 
Password:
Searching for scrapy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/scrapy/
Best match: Scrapy 1.0.3
Processing Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
Scrapy 1.0.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for scrapy
Finished processing dependencies for scraps
```

But when i enter scrapy again, the result was still disappointed.

```
scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2797, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: lxml
```

Anyone even just give me a hint would be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

This is what usually works for me

Comment: This is not a mac commad